# Kubernetes pod HPA not working during maintenance/upgrades Worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I have implemented HPA for all the pods based on CPU and it was working as expected. But when we did a maintenance of worker nodes, it seems tha HPA's got messed up as it failed to identify it. Do I need to disable HPA temporarily during maintenance and bring it up once the maitenance is over.

Please suggest

HPA Manifest -

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: pod-name-cpu
spec:
  maxReplicas: 6
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: pod-name
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
```

Comment: Can you share your HPA manifest and how did you perform maintenance? Did you cordon the nodes?

Comment: HPA Manifest added in the original question. Yes the node is cordoned

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "maintenance"? Was an update strategy for deployments used? What was expected and how did HPA react? Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [maintenance-mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#implicit-maintenance-mode-deactivation) solution which says:

> You can implicitly deactivate the HPA for a target without the need to
> change the HPA configuration itself. If the target's desired replica
> count is set to 0, and the HPA's minimum replica count is greater than
> 0, the HPA stops adjusting the target (and sets the `ScalingActive`
> Condition on itself to `false`) until you reactivate it by manually
> adjusting the target's desired replica count or HPA's minimum replica
> count.

**EDIT:**

To explain more the above, the things you should do are:

- Scale your deployment to `0`
- Describe your `HPA`
- Notice that under the `Conditions:` section the `ScalingActive` will turn to `False` which will disable `HPA` until you set the replicas back to desired value
- See more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#appendix-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-status-conditions)

Also, as you did not specify what exactly happened and what is the desired outcome you might also consider moving your workload into a different node.
[How to perform Disruptive Actions on your Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-to-perform-disruptive-actions-on-your-cluster) has a few options for you to choose from.

Comment: @sam I have added some more info for my answer. Please take a look.